# Angular CLI not downgrading from v 8.1.3

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular app running with angular-cli version 8.1.3. I want to downgrade to angular-cli v7.0.3.
I have done

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.3
```

So when I do ng --version I excepted that the vangular cli version will be 7.0.3,
but it was 8.1.3.

I have tried doing it multiple times,but the result is same. What can be the reason?

Comment: What's the local *project's* Angular CLU version?

Answer (score 1):

These command are both working fine

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.3
```

You need to use ng new command in different folder so that your command can take effect

Also you can check version of angular cli in your computer by this command

```
npm view @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do `npm install @angular/cli@7.0.3` inside your project and make sure that you run `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` first.